# How to add lists of data in python in a predefined array inside a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7, matlab

How to add lists of data  in python in a predefined array inside a for loop ?

Like in mat-lab this statement works

```
for a=1:10
d=a*1000;
X1(a,:)=M(c+1:d,1)';
c=d;
end
```

Comment: Python doesn't have arrays, pre-defined or otherwise.

Comment: for a in range (1,11):
d = a * 1000
U.append(X[c+1:d+1,0])
c = d****  it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can this by using `np.append()`, or faster (if you know what the size of your array will be) by using `np.zeros()` or `np.empty()`.